# Difficult integral, maybe multidimensional contour integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to solve
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}d^3k\frac{e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{\rho}}}{|\theta|+k^2}$$
I have a feeling that I should use contour integration, but in three variables I do not know how to employ it. Moreover, Mathematica cannot solve it for me.

I should say that I have some notes that say that I should pass from a form like $-i4\pi\int_{-1}^{1}d\cos\theta\int_0^\infty\frac{dk\sin(kr)}{|\theta|+k^2}$ but I do not know why.

I'd appreciate a help in solving that.

Comment: Since you are a new user, you should explains what  did you try. In this way, it would be easier for any user to help you.

Comment: In the integral, do you mean $\rho^2=k^2$ ?

Comment: V.Rossetto, you are right. Corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}
{\expo{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{\rho}} \over \verts{\theta} + k^{2}}\,\dd^{3}\vec{k}
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dd k\,
{4\pi k^{2}\, \over \verts{\theta} + k^{2}}\,
\overbrace{\int\expo{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{\rho}}\,{\dd\Omega_{\vec{k}} \over 4\pi}}
^{\ds{=\ {\sin\pars{k\rho} \over k\rho}}}
\\[3mm]&=
{4\pi \over \rho^{3}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\rho\dd k\,
{\pars{k\rho}^{2} \over \verts{\theta} +\pars{k\rho}^{2}/\rho^{2}}
\,{\sin\pars{k\rho} \over k\rho}
\\[3mm]&=
{4\pi \over \rho}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\sin\pars{x} \over k^{2} + \mu^{2}}\,\dd x\quad
\mbox{where}\quad\mu \equiv \rho\verts{\theta}^{1/2}\,,\quad \rho \equiv \verts{\vec{\rho}}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> \int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}
> {\expo{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{\rho}} \over \verts{\theta} + k^{2}}\,\dd^{3}\vec{k}
> &={2\pi \over \rho}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x\sin\pars{x} \over k^{2} + \mu^{2}}\,\dd x
> =
> {2\pi \over \rho}\,
> \Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x\expo{\ic x} \over k^{2} + \mu^{2}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&={2\pi \over \rho}\,
> \Im\bracks{2\pi\ic\,{\ic\mu\expo{\ic\pars{\ic\mu}} \over \ic\mu + \ic\mu}}
> ={2\pi^{2} \over \rho}\expo{-\mu}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{3}}
{\expo{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{\rho}} \over \verts{\theta} + k^{2}}\,\dd^{3}\vec{k}
=
{2\pi^{2} \over \rho}\expo{-\rho\root{\verts{\theta}}}}
$$

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks! You spared me much time, I have never seen that substitution of the sine

Comment: @Rimon It's a usual one since $\large{\rm e}^{{\rm i}\theta} = \cos\left(\theta\right) + {\rm i}\sin\left(\theta\right)$. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I was referring to the first substitution (in polar coordinates?)